# How to append to a field in Capybara (Webdriver) rather than clear and populate

Tags: capybara

I'm a newbie to Capybara. I'm using the WebDriver driver and I would like to append to a field value as opposed to overwrite the entire contents.

When I use the method fill_in, it overwrites the whole value (clears and then populates). However I want to just append to an existing value in the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [`send_keys`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FElement%3Asend_keys) will be your friend.

Try `find_field('Your field').native.send_keys('some text')`

Comment: thanks mate, you are the most awesome person in this universe!

Answer (score 0):

May be you would like to do it in this way specifically in **Capybara**

```
    def anyMethod
      locator_strategy = :css
      if(obj_locator[0]=='/' || obj_locator[0,2] == '(/'))
        locator_strategy = :xpath
      end
      find(locator_strategy, locator_path).native.send_keys('some text')
    end
```