# Capybaras fill_in resulting in Net::ReadTimeout with large character counts

Tags: selenium, automation, cucumber, capybara, headless

Running in Ubuntu 14.04 using Cucumber, Capybara and Selenium with Firefox browser headlessly.

Ran into this issue when trying to fill text fields with data containing more than 12 000 characters.

Until 12 000 characters the fill_in seems to work ok, but when the content is more 12 000 chars, im getting Net::ReadTimeouts no matter how long I set the timeout to be.

It seems that somewhere capybara (or something else) gets stuck with large character counts when using fill_in.

DEBUG=True is on but not showing any relevant info, other than the timeout...

Any idea what could help here?

Comment: I would want to know why you would need to fill 12k + characters. As an alternative maybe you can  use some other script to fill the field or split your string and try method to append, for append see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485221/how-to-append-to-a-field-in-capybara-webdriver-rather-than-clear-and-populate

Comment: @lauda, moving data inside an information system via web interface utilizing automated scripts.

Comment: @lauda Thanks alot! The problem was solved by splitting the string and utilizing append.

Comment: You are welcome. You can add your solution and accept the answer.